# Is something wrong at LifeHacks?

Tags: support

I have tried several questions over the last few minutes, but get nothing but the "Oops! Something bad happened." page.

Is this just happening to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Cross site 500 error on question pages**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277523/98786)

> This was a bug in pathing that should never be allowed to bring down question pages anyway - a fix has been deployed and I'll be preventing that code from causing such drastic issues ever again in my next commit.